# CSS3 problem with animation when unchecking a checkbox

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to recreate my form's checkboxes by CSS3.

I animated the mark (checkbox) correctly, but when I uncheck the checkbox I can't start the animation in reverse mode. [I reproduced my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-grothendieck-51qfj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

```css
/*
==================
INPUT CHECKBOX
==================
*/

.checkbox-label>input {
  display: none;
  outline: none;
}


/*
==============
LABEL CHECKBOX
==============
*/

.checkbox-label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.95em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
}

.checkbox-label:hover>.checkbox-button {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px hsla(255, 100%, 60%, 0.1);
  background-color: hsla(255, 100%, 60%, 0.1);
}

.checkbox-label:hover>.checkbox-button {
  border: 2px solid #808080;
}


/*
======================
MARK CHECKBOX - AFTER
======================
*/

.checkbox-label>input[type="checkbox"]~.checkbox-button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 3px;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}


/*
================================
MARK CHECKBOX - AFTER - CHECKED
================================
*/

.checkbox-label>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.checkbox-button::after {
  animation: checkbox-check 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.23, 1);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.checkbox-label:not(:active)>input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)~.checkbox-button::after {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}


/*
========
CHECKBOX
========
*/

.checkbox-button {
  vertical-align: sub;
}

.checkbox-button {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: #808080;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}

.checkbox-label>input:checked~.checkbox-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #6633ff;
  background-color: #6633ff;
}

.checkbox-label>input~.checkbox-button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #6633ff;
  border-radius: 30%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.checkbox-label>input:checked~.checkbox-button::before {
  animation: ripple 0.9s ease-out;
}


/*
==========
ANIMATION
==========
*/

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes checkbox-check {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-color: white;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
  33% {
    width: 5px;
    height: 0px;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    width: 5px;
    height: 11px;
    border-color: white;
    transform: translate3d(0, -11px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="form">
  <h1>Custom Checkboxe</h1>
  <label class="checkbox-label" data-label="One">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <span class="checkbox-button"></span>
        One
  </label>
</form>
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to improve to make my animation work properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Andrea! In the future be sure to include the code relevant to your problem in the question itself, even if you link out to it as well.